# Error : replacement has x rows, data has y

Tags: r, matrix, plm, renjin

I am running this R script from Java (I am using Renjin):

```
getCoefficients <- function(x, y, Regions) {
  nbRegions <- length(Regions)
  lengthY <- length(y)
  colRegions <- NULL
  from <- 1
  to <- lengthY / nbRegions
  for (i in 1:nbRegions) {
    region <- Regions[i]
    c <- cbind(region, from:to)
    colRegions <- rbind(colRegions, c)
  }
  indexCols <- as.data.frame(colRegions)
  x_ <- t(x)
  data_ <- cbind(indexCols, y, x_)
  dataFrame <- data.frame(data_)
  colnames(dataFrame) <- c("region", "date", "y", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "r", "o")
  print(colnames(dataFrame))
  model_RE_S <- try(plm(y ~ x_, data = dataFrame, model = "random", index = c("region", "date"), effect = "twoways"))
  summryModel <- summary(model_RE_S)
  coeff <- as.numeric(summryModel$coefficients)
  #print(summryModel)
  
  return(coeff)
}
```

I am getting the following error and I have no idea how to resolve it:

```
Error : replacement has 3648 rows, data has 456
```

the x is a 456*8 matrix, the y is 456*1, and 3 regions.

**Update: an alternative: **
I got rid of Renjin and used **Rserve** instead.

Comment: In formula try `y ~ .` that means that y will depend on everything but himself. You do get to plm part?

Comment: I tried it and: `Error: duplicate couples (time-id)`